# How to start function after previous function finishes in React Native

Tags: javascript, promise, react-native

I have a problem. I know I can use promises to fix this problem, but I do not understand how to use them in my case. I just want get `id` from a function in another file (let's call it callApi), and then use this `id` to call another function, callApi2. The problem is callApi2 runs before apiCall finishes.

```js
ApiCariIdAktor = {
  cariIdAktor: () => {
    const apikey = APP_CONSTANT.api_key;
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=${apikey}&language=en-US&query=iko%20uwais&page=1&include_adult=false`;
    let id = 0;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        responseJson.results[0].id
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    return 10;
  }
}

setID() {
  this.state.id = ApiCariIdAktor.cariIdAktor();
}

async componentDidMount() {
  this.setID();
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
  this.panggilApi2();
}
```

Comment: `return fetch(...)` and `responseJson.results[0].id`. Delete the `catch()` Change `setID()` to `async setID()` and `this.state.id = await ApiCariIdAktor.cariIdAktor();`. In `componentDidMount()`, `await this.setID();`.

Comment: like thiscariIdAktor:() => {
        const apikey = APP_CONSTANT.api_key;
        const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=${apikey}&language=en-US&query=iko%20uwais&page=1&include_adult=false`;
        return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=> {
                responseJson.results[0].id
        })
    }

Comment: You are still not returning `responseJson.results[0].id`. That's key because whatever is returned from the final `.then()` is what gets delivered by the promise returned by the function.